# closing child window automatically when the parent window is closed

Tags: javascript

I want the code so that the chilld window closes as soon as the parent window is closed in asp.net.?

How can this be achieved?

Comment: This is a javascript trick, not an asp.net. Can you provide some code, how do you open the child window ?

Comment: i am opening the child window by clicking a hyperlink.
now i want if i close the parent window,the child window i.e child.aspx should be closed..
tell me in javascript

Comment: you should keep a reference to the childwindow in the parent window (make sure it opens with javascript and not by default href ), add a listener to the window closing event of the parent window that will close all child windows.

Comment: how to do that...i dont know...can u help me in detail..

Answer (score 1):

Too bad that "dependent" no longer works.
As Redlab commented, you need to keep track.
Some browsers will not execute script that is called from the unload event, but try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var childWin = [];
function openWin(link) {
  var childWin[childWin.length] = window.open(link.href,link.target,'dependent');
  return childWin[childWin.length-1]?false:true; // if popup blocker
}
function closeWin() {
  for (var i=0;i<childWin.length;i++) {
    if (childWin[i] && !childWin[i].closed) childWin[i].close();
  }
}
window.onunload=function() { closeWin(); }

</script>


<a href="page.html" target="_blank" onClick="return openWin(this)">Pop</a>
```